# laravel mutator that creates a unique random number does not run

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Question model like this:

```
class Question extends Model
    {
        use SoftDeletes;

        protected $primaryKey = 'question_id';
        protected $dates      = ['deleted_at'];
        protected $fillable   = ['text', 'code', 'cat', 'answer', 'is_private', 'email', 'parent'];


        public function setCodeAttribute ($value)
        {
            \Debugbar::info('hello');

            do {
                $code      = rand(10000, 10000000);
                $user_code = User::where('code', $code)->get();

            } while (!$user_code->isEmpty());

            return $this->attributes['code'] = $code;
        }

    }
```

I want to generate a random integer number and store that in `code` field on creation of a new instance of the model.

For that I wrote a mutator as you can see but it did not even run.

What is problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well mutator itself do not run untill you don't call `$question->code = $someValue`.

What you need is [observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#observers) and define `saving` method in it that will provide setting of the `code` attribute value in it like this:

```
    public function saving (Operation $operation)
    {
        \Debugbar::info('hello');

        do {
            $code      = rand(10000, 10000000);
            $user_code = User::where('code', $code)->get();

        } while (!$user_code->isEmpty());

        return $operation->code = $code;
    }
```

and of corse you need to delete the mutator from the  model class as well.